# How to group data by one values?

Tags: reactjs, grouping

I have data table which I want to group by one value, "Group 1" and "Group 2".
How can I do this? [this is how my table look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHncD.png)

I map this data from json file:

```
data.properties.map(data =>({key: Math.floor(Math.random()*1234), id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1234), value: data.value, group: data.group, type: data.type, label: data.label, image: data.image}));
```

then I put it as InitialState to state.
If it isn't enough I just please to explain me how to group data by group on this code example:

`const items = [{
id: 1,
group: "Group 1",
title: "My Title 1"
}, {
id: 2,
group: "Group 2",
title: "My title 2"
}, {
id: 6,
group: "Group 1",
title: "Another title 1"
}]`

You can do it on example or use my data, doesn't matter,  I am sorry if I ask stupid question, thank you!

Comment: Please include relevant stuff in the question, not external links to pictures of code. What sample output are you wanting? There's plenty of posts about grouping objects via a property value, you can google search for them. Do they not fulfil your needs?

Answer (score 1):

you can use array.reduce().. maybe something like this can get you started:

```
const arr = [
  {
    group: 'Group 1',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    group: 'Group 1',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    group: 'Group 2',
    id: 3
  }
];

const x = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  const idx = acc.findIndex(el => el.group === cur.group);
  const obj = {
    group: cur.group
  };
  if(idx < 0) {
    obj.children = [];
    obj.children.push(cur);
    acc.push(obj)
  } else {
    acc[idx].children.push(cur);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it will be very helpful for me. Can I ask you about "(acc,cur)", where this variables are assinged to? What are they doing?

Comment: @bigmacreact sorry, I was a away for a few days.. the acc = accumulator, the cur = current value.. search google for javascript array reduce.. :)

Comment: Thanks, can I ask you one more question? If I would to display subgroup, I mean rest values, how to inicjate this in the store? Something like using group.values or what?